# How to apply FAB (Material UI) to span 2 columns in a CSS Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I get the zero button to span 2 columns so that its bigger than the other buttons in its row? I want it to be a bigger oval. Thanks for your help.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Fab from '@mui/material/Fab';

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className = "blank"> </div>
      <div className = "btn-container-div"> 
      <div className = "screen-div"> </div>
      
      <div className = "row"> 
      <Fab> AC </Fab>
      <Fab> +/- </Fab>
      <Fab> &#37; </Fab>
      <Fab> &#247; </Fab>
      </div>
      <div className = "row"> 
      <Fab> 7 </Fab>
      <Fab> 8 </Fab>
      <Fab> 9 </Fab>
      <Fab> &#215; </Fab>
      </div>
      <div className = "row"> 
      <Fab> 4 </Fab>
      <Fab> 5 </Fab>
      <Fab> 6 </Fab>
      <Fab> &#247; </Fab>
      </div>
      <div className = "row"> 
      <Fab> AC </Fab>
      <Fab> +/- </Fab>
      <Fab> % </Fab>
      <Fab> &#8722; </Fab>
      </div>
      <div className = "row"> 
      <Fab> 0 </Fab>
      <Fab> . </Fab>
      <Fab> &#61; </Fab>
      </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  display: grid;
  background:black;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 10fr;
}

.blank {
  background: red;
}

.btn-container-div {
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6,1fr);
  
}

.screen-div {
  background: white;
}

.row{
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}
```

How can I get the zero button to span 2 columns so that its bigger than the other buttons in its row? I want it to be a bigger oval. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Comment: That doesn't help me. The FAB just moves to the center of the expanded row.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I added a className to the fab, then just did grid-column: span 2 in css.